# Resolved shear stress - direction

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

The shear stress in a crystal can be described as follows: $τ=R σ_{xx}$, where $σ_{xx}$ is the tensile load and R the Schmid factor. Can the shear stress now be assigned to a defined direction?

Comment: Are you asking why shear stress can be assigned to be an in-plane stress when the tensile load is a perpendicular stress? Or are you asking to show a derivation of the Schmid's law expression from first principles using vector notations?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation. The question is certainly very trivial. If I have the tensile stress σ_{xx}, this also leads to a shear stress τ_{xx}?

Comment: Yes, if you have the applied tensile stress $\sigma$ normal to a specific direction in the bulk, single crystal material, Schmid's law leads to the resolved shear stress $\tau$ on a specific plane pointing in a specific (slip) direction.